# help with a string like no other

Tags: design, sound, synthesizer, replication

This string sound

I have tried so many variations and I still can't nail, many forums later no one else can seem to either

you can hear the string on it's own @1.23

State Of Grace - Not Over Yet (Trance Mix) 1993 - YouTube

can you help?

is it a sample or is it synth layered? or both?

I've never heard a string like it

scott

Comment: Your video won't play.

Comment: type in "grace - not over yet" its the string before the chorus I think around 50 seconds

Answer (score 1):

The clip at 1:23 sounds to me like an 80's synth set to an Organ setting or a horn's setting. Check out some of these clips

The OBX and OBX-a synts were big in the 80's its what EVH used on Jump